# wxPython main thread other than 0 leads to wxWidgets Debug Alert on exit

Tags: python, multithreading, exit, wxpython

I want to use interactive wxPython GUIs simultaneously with a console session (like matplotlib in interactive mode). This requires the console to continue to run on thread 0 and all wx interactions to run on a separate thread. (I'm well aware only one thread should access wx.)

My demo code below works (when launched via `python -i`), but pops up a wxWidgets Debug Alert (looks like a crash dialog) when I exit Python (e.g. via `exit()`). **How can I avoid the alert when exiting Python when the wx main thread is not thread 0?**

```
import threading

class GUI(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        import wx 
        app = wx.App() 
        window = wx.Frame(None, title="Hello World!", size=(200, 100)) 
        panel = wx.Panel(window) 
        text = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Hello World!", pos=(0, 0)) 
        window.Show(True) 
        app.MainLoop()     

gui_thread = GUI()
gui_thread.start()
```

[Others](https://wiki.wxpython.org/MainLoopAsThread) report success using strategies like this with older versions of wxPython, but their code (case 3) gives me the same crash on shut down as the above.

The error I get on exit (maybe from an automatically registered `atexit` handler?) is the same you'd get if you tried to access wx from a second thread: `assert "wxIsMathThread()" failed in wxSocketBase::IsInitialized(): unsafe to call from other threads [in thread 1b68]`.

Specifically, I get the wxWidgets Debug Alert when running wxPython 4.0.1 (aka Phoenix) on Windows 10 with Anaconda Python 3.6.3. I have not tested other platforms and versions.

Comment: Are you making any effort to end the GUI before you kill the process?  I think your theory about the an auto-registered handler is probably correct.  Also is it really a crash if it happens after exit()?

Comment: Importing wx registers two atexit handlers, so that's probably part of the story. I modified the question to show that the message that pops up is labeled as a "wxWidgets Debug Alert" and so arguably not a crash. Note: these alerts are enabled by default; see: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__debug.html#g8db18cbe95b3b42c3017a8bf048b0839

Answer (score 3):

The alert is coming from an `atexit` handler automatically inserted by importing `wx`. To avoid this while still allowing routine debugging, one can disable alerts `atexit` after `wx` is loaded:

```
import threading
import atexit

class GUI(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        import wx 
        atexit.register(disable_asserts)
        app = wx.App() 
        window = wx.Frame(None, title="Hello World!", size=(200, 100)) 
        panel = wx.Panel(window) 
        text = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Hello World!", pos=(0, 0)) 
        window.Show(True) 
        app.MainLoop()

def disable_asserts():
    import wx
    wx.DisableAsserts()

gui_thread = GUI()
gui_thread.start()
```